# Replace the default post categories with custom taxonomy - Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Is there any way that I can replace the default post categories that appear in the right sidebar with custom categories/taxonomy?

I have custom taxonomy for products and I already have categories there.

I want to use the same custom product categories in the posts without recreating them. Is this possible?

And when I write a post and if a user clicks on the category, this should link them to the product category, not the post category.

Comment: Take a look at my answer on this [link] (http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/261572/111577)